# Background image returning 404 Github HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, image, web, background

First, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Where the magic happens</title>
    <style>
      body {
      background-image: url('synthwave.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <div><h1>Home Page</hi></h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having problems to display the background image. Please note that my synthwave.png image is located in the same folder as the index.html file. The terminal shows:

`127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2023 12:03:29] "GET /machec/synthwave.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

I have already tried modifying the file route, and changing folders, but I cannot make the background image to show up. I also know that it is a best practice to move everything css into its own file, but this is a super small website project. Thanks in advance y'all

Comment: Double-check the spelling of `synthwave.png`. Capitalization could be a factor as well.

Comment: Thanks! Spelling was right, and I could never make it work this way (even though I was able to prevent the 404 error, the image then would not display). I fixed it by changing the url to a cloud location.